# How do I add an attribute to an R data.frame while I'm making it with a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes, attr

Let's say I have an R data.frame:

`> x <- data.frame()`

I also have a SQL query I am building with sprintf():

```
> (query <- sprintf("select %s from %s %s", "names", "name_table", "where age > 20"))
[1] "select names from name_table where age > 20"
```

I intend to encase this in in a function in order to fill the data.frame `x` with the results from `query`, and just for a few sprinkles on top I want to tell my future self what `query` was used to generate the data.frame `x`.  I'd like to do this with a call to `attr()` like so:

```
> attr(x, "query") <- query
> str(x)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
 - attr(*, "query")= chr "select names from name_table where age > 20"
```

Because the function is going to look something like

```
answer_maker <- function(col_names, table_name, condtions) {

                   query <- sprintf("select %s from %s %s", col_names, table_name, conditions)

                   data.frame(sql(query))

    ############## WHAT DO I DO HERE? 
    ############## I want to type something py-like ...self.attr()?
                   attr(self, "query") <- query
               }
```

Later on I will be able to do the following

```
> my_first_answer <- answer_maker("names", "name_table", "where age > 20")
> attr(my_first_answer, "query")
[1] "select names from name_table where age > 20"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that database functions in R typically return a data frame so you don't have to fill an empty existing one.  Below we use the sqldf package to keep the example self-contained and reproducible but you can substitute whatever sort of database access you are using.  (Typically you will need to create a data base connection and pass it into `answer_maker` but in this example since we are using sqldf it was not needed.)

```
library(sqldf)   
name_table <- data.frame(names = letters, age = 1:26) # test data

answer_maker <- function(col_names, table_name, conditions) {
      query <- sprintf("select %s from %s %s", col_names, table_name, conditions)
      ans <- sqldf(query)
      attr(ans, "query") <- query
      ans
}

ans <- answer_maker("names", "name_table", "where age > 20")
```

giving:

```
> ans
  names
1     u
2     v
3     w
4     x
5     y
6     z

> attr(ans, "query")
[1] "select names from name_table where age > 20"
```

**Reference Classes**  Using R's reference classes we can define a class with data and query fields and methods which store the query and run it such that each outputs the object  using `.self` :

```
Query <- setRefClass("Query", fields = c("data", "query"),
   methods = list(
      setQuery = function(col_names, table_name, conditions) {
          query <<- sprintf("select %s from %s %s", col_names, table_name, conditions)
          .self
      },
      runQuery = function() {
          data <<- sqldf(query)
          .self
      }))

qq <- Query$
        new()$
        setQuery("names", "name_table", "where age > 20")$
        runQuery()
```

giving:

```
> qq$data
  names
1     u
2     v
3     w
4     x
5     y
6     z
> qq$query
[1] "select names from name_table where age > 20"
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  But does your response imply that there is no `self.thing` style of assignment within a constructor object like this?

Comment: If you are looking for an OO style then there are many object systems (S3, S4, Reference Classes) plus several packages whichi define additional OO systems (proto, oo.R, R6).  We illustrate reference classes in the added section on reference classes at the end of the answer.